# What is this military march sampled in "Hell March"?

Tags: military, identification, game

The video game *Command & Conquer: Red Alert* features a song titled [Hell March](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3YzmjmAGoI) by Frank Klepacki, which includes a [voice sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJlZWmyNAYY) of an unidentified military officer.

The sample appears to originate in the [Series 1000 Sound Effects Library](https://soundeffects.fandom.com/wiki/Series_1000_Sound_Effects_Library#Drill.2C_Military), originally released on reel-to-reel tape in 1979 and on compact disc in 1983, and may also have appeared in [Network Sound Effects Library](https://soundeffects.fandom.com/wiki/Network_Sound_Effects_Library). Series 1000 is described as a collection of sound effects from the 1960s and 1970s, although it does include audio clips from at least as far back a WWII. The sample in question is from Series 1000 Sound Effects Library CD 1019, titled [Drill, Military - Footsteps, Orders Being Shouted, Marching, Soldiers 03](https://soundeffects.fandom.com/wiki/Sound_Ideas,_DRILL,_MILITARY_-_FOOTSTEPS,_ORDERS_BEING_SHOUTED,_MARCHING,_SOLDIERS_03).

The sample begins with a military officer giving a command, followed by a group of soldiers marching at a pace of around 100 steps per minute. It's not clear what language the officer is speaking, and I'm not sure which modern militaries or parade groups march at this pace (e.g. a quick march of 120 steps per minute seems common). The sample [Soldiers 02](https://soundeffects.fandom.com/wiki/Sound_Ideas,_DRILL,_MILITARY_-_FOOTSTEPS,_ORDERS_BEING_SHOUTED,_MARCHING,_SOLDIERS_02) sounds like the same officer, and [this sample](https://soundeffects.fandom.com/wiki/Sound_Ideas,_MUSIC,_MILITARY_-_DRUM_SOLO:_DRUMS_STOP_ON_COMMAND,_MARCHING,_DRUMS,_SOLDIERS) with drums may possibly be from the same event.

A great deal of speculation has been made online regarding what the officer is saying, but most of this is not useful. The most common answers are either complete guesses (i.e. "It sounds to me like he's saying..."), or repeating popular guesses made by others online (most commonly "die Waffen legt an" - I'm very skeptical of this one, since a search for `"die Waffen legt an" site:de` reveals few results and they're all talking about the video game). In [an interview](https://youtu.be/6t4rd1D2GhM?t=1150), the song's composer admits that he also does not know what the officer is saying. **To be clear, I'm not interested in guesses or summaries of other people's guesses found online.**

Regarding these samples, then:

1. What military, group, or event are these samples ([Soldiers 02](https://soundeffects.fandom.com/wiki/Sound_Ideas,_DRILL,_MILITARY_-_FOOTSTEPS,_ORDERS_BEING_SHOUTED,_MARCHING,_SOLDIERS_02), [Soldiers 03](https://soundeffects.fandom.com/wiki/Sound_Ideas,_DRILL,_MILITARY_-_FOOTSTEPS,_ORDERS_BEING_SHOUTED,_MARCHING,_SOLDIERS_03)) a recording of?
2. What is the officer actually saying in these samples?

Comment: Not sure where the historical ur disciplinary content is.

Comment: The command "Legt an" (to start marching) can be heard. Before that, the group name (which I didn't reconize) is used, so that the group knows who the command is for. I couldn't understand the second command. A **Schneller Marsch**: is between 100 and 120 steps/min (75 cm to 100 cm ; 4.5–7.2 km/h). Since 1813, the German army uses 114 (80 cm).

Comment: @SamuelRussell The question is trying to identify a sound recording of a military march. I've seen questions similarly trying to identify military photographs.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Are there sources which support that any military uses "legt an" as a command to start a march? My concern is that this is yet another subjective hearing rather than an identification. I've also heard "quick march", which is consistent with the 100 steps/min.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard For the military, it would be strange since 'Legt an' is used for 'aim' or to prepare a gun salut. The Fire Department (Feuerwehr), which would normaly also use 'Marsch!', does use 'Legt an' to start a predefined activity, which is stated before that. The audio is a public event (a croud with children can be heard). The first step of the march can be heard after 'Legt an'. Without understanding the previous term, the given context remains unknown. [PDF: FwDV 10 Feuerwehr-Dienstvorschrift 10 - IdF NRW](https://www.idf.nrw.de/service/downloads/pdf/fwdv10.pdf)

Comment: @MarkJohnson According to that document, page 13, "legt an" is used only in the command "Schiebleiter - legt an!" (Schiebleiter = telescopic ladder), presumably using the meaning of [anlegen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anlegen) of "lay out". It's not the command to begin marching with the ladder - that's "Schiebleiter - marsch!".

Comment: @QuadraticWizard In this context it can also mean **apply** the previously given commands. With the word 'Legt', often drawn out ('Leeeeeegt'), the listeners know that the commands have ended and prepair themselfs to start. With a sharp 'an' is the signal to start. [What does "legt an" mean in German?](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-meaning-of/german-word-296f5fd9842edaba138bd97978a79cd7e0381d8d.html)

Comment: The audio 02 (same voice) is in english **present arms**. Again the preceding word is not clear.

Comment: For the present German army 'legt an' is still 'take aim', and ZDv 3/2 lists the common formalised  commands. 'Start marching' is always "Marsch!" (with various qualifiers before)? To me, the whole clip sounds like a potpourri _montage_ (the steps sound strange in comparison) of _barked_ commands, _intentionally_ unlear/indiscernible, alluding to militarism from Germany (but either NVA or previous, not so much regular BW) or what we see on 'Trooping the Colours' for British equivalents?

Comment: @QuadraticWizard,LangLangC I would also agree that these audios are a potpourri creation considering that the same voice uses 2 different languages, the German version of which would not be used by the military or police in this context.

Comment: I hadn't heard the original samples (without the music) before. Now that I have, I don't think that's German in the first place. I've done a round or two around the parade ground getting all the commands in the book yelled at me, and while I understand how people could believe to hear a "legt an!" here, it 1) doesn't sound right, and b) makes zero sense in the context even of an exhibition parade. I think "trying to hear" German here is a red herring. There's so many other languages around, it doesn't have to be either English or German.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard have you considered reaching out to Sound Ideas? I would be shocked if they did not maintain provenance of the clips in their archive.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I know it's been a long time since your comment, but I feel it needs correcting -- it's definitely not "present arms" in German (that would be "Präsentiert das Gewehr").

Answer (score -1):

"Die Waffen legt an!"  in context means "Aim your weapons now"... to understand: when an army officer shouts to it's soldiers during either an official march or at an army cadence or drill he can shout that as like an order to raise the gun in a certain manner... but also when someone gets executed by shooting like for some war prisoner back in WW2... the execution bataillon or however it is called will be standing in a row to shoot the person who gets killed. The officer will then shout something like "Die Waffen legt an!" Or only "legt an" (meaning raise your weapons now... then "Zielt!" (means "aim!") and finally "Feuern!" (Meaning "Fire!")...so yeah this sample has a real gruesome and sad back ground... you must know that a verb alone with only a "!" is considered like an order in German language. However I am no language teacher and the context is quite hard to explain so I hope I was able to explain this here a bit as best as I can ^^... just in case I am German living in Munich ^^ I hope that helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure this answers the question.

Comment: "Aim your weapon" is not a command an officer would give during a parade a drill. "Fire" is a command given at a shooting range, never during a parade. That scares innocent bystanders somewhat.